Cross tenant connection: How to establish a connection between an Azure resource in PME tenant and D365 environment which is in Microsoft tenant
Trying to establish a connection between an Azure resource in PME tenant and D365 environment which is in Microsoft tenant.
We tried by creating a cross-tenant service principle but still unable to connect from Azure resource in PME to D365 environment in Microsoft tenant
